# ServiceStack Axios URL special charaters

Tags: c#, api, axios, servicestack, restful-url

What is the best way to deal with special characters in URL's with ServiceStack and a Javascript Axios client, or any other client.

Example:
URL Path: /MasterItems/{Code} - Code can have any character in it, (/ \ & etc.)

The above URL could be generated by the API (backend), so it will come back from a previous request as part of the response _links.

Example: of the response _links
/MasterItems/A1200G/FA (the code is A1200G/FA)

My frontend code, (VueJS, Javascript, Axios) will simply get the _links resource and call the GET.

How should I treat this, turn my GET into POST and pass a parameter?
Encode the URL?

Note:
I noticed when using the built-in swagger feature of ServiceStack the resulting call works.
The URL will be: /MasterItems/%7BCode%7D?Code=A1200G%2FA

Comment: I'd strongly recommend avoiding adding any special chars in the /path/info, add them to the queryString instead where they're more consistently properly encoded/decoded.

Comment: The API is built on hypermedia or HATEOAS. So the response object includes links with href to navigate the resources operations. Reference https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/